# How to add custom text editor in add post section?

Tags: plugins, text

How can I add custom text editor in wordpress? Is there any way to do that?

If not, How can I add or remove certain features from it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which features do you want to add or remove? knowing that will help determine whether it's possible with the default tinymce editor. tinymce is very strongly integrated with wordpress, so attempting to use another one is likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TinyMCE,CKeditor plugin.

Comment: Isn't TinyMCE the default editor? I will checkout CKeditor plugin. Can you tell me how can I add or remove certain features from it?

Comment: Yes, TinyMCE is default editor. Ultimate tinyMCE is good.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/